# how to fix NPM install packages, that give an error back

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

[Here's the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwXnJ.png)

After installing (`npm init`) I try:

```
$ npm install express
```

Same thing happens if I try to install any other package.

```
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\c3\ae\1314e79200fca71af4663702ee1e676113e408ca8a468a396de5ab6d5d2b
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\c3\ae\1314e79200fca71af4663702ee1e676113e408ca8a468a396de5ab6d5d2b'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-17T17_14_26_890Z-debug.log
```

What might this error be?

Comment: tried clearing the npm cache ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove following directory and try again **npm update**. It works for me.

*C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache*

Answer (score 0):

Some issues can be solved by clearing the cache with `npm cache clean`.
Run this command and try again. If it still doesn't work, use the -verbose argument to get more output on the installation to see more details.

Comment: Thank you friend, for the help
But it sends 

$ npm cache clean
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.

Comment: Right, you need to pass the `--force` option to run this command: `npm cache clean --force`. But you could still try `npm cache verify` first or use a temporary cache like the message suggests if you're unsure.

Comment: tried both and still no good..

```$ npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall scandir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\c3
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\c3'

$ npm cache verify
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall scandir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\c3
npm ERR! errno -4094
```

Comment: Try to use the `--save` flag when installing a module like express. If the module is mandatory for your project to work, it should be in your dependency list anyway. If you want to install a module globally, you need to use the `-g` argument and also run it as administrator.

Comment: same thing happends 
```$ npm install --save express
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\c3\ae\1314e79200fca71af4663702ee1e676113e408ca8a468a396de5ab6d5d2b
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\index-v5\c3\ae\1314e79200fca71af4663702ee1e676113e408ca8a468a396de5ab6d5d2b'```


It installed packages fine a week ago with no problems, but now it just sends me all these errors.

Comment: What happens if you remove your node_modules folder and run `npm install` again?